# Stream of random values with Rng library

Tags: scala, random, stream, scalaz

I am looking through [Rng](https://github.com/NICTA/rng) sources to see how they generate a stream of random values.

```
def stream[AA >: A](s: Size): Rng[EphemeralStream[AA]] = 
  list(s) map (EphemeralStream(_: _*))
```

First of all I am confused with this signature. I need a generator of an *infinite* stream that yields random values lazily. So I do not need the `size` argument.

I am confused with the implementation too. The generator seems to create a list and then *convert* it to the stream. However the whole point of the stream is to be lazy. What am I missing ?

Comment: `Stream` is allowed to be fixed-size. Perhaps this method only allows creating fixed-length `Stream`s, not infinite ones?

Comment: @lmm Yes, you are right. I should probably rephrase my question: How to write a generator of an _infinite_ stream of random values with `Rng` ?

Comment: Does it have to be using `Stream`? My understanding was that for new development scalaz was encouraging people to use `Process`, under which it's fairly simple to write a process that outputs infinite `Rng` random values.

Comment: No, it does not. I hoped it was not tricky to write a function: `Rng[A] => Rng[Stream[A]]`.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but important: The library might be OK in some cases, where you don't have strong requirements on the random numbers quality. I however strongly discourage for using it for crypto. I've checked how they do generate the numbers. They seem not to be using any existing library for that purpose. A custom implementation might come with some side channels and be vulnerable to, say, timing attack. Moreover, I have Googled for Kleisli-based RNGs and haven't found any serious (or even not serious) reasoning, just some implementation in Scala and Haskell.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about `Stream`, but we can do something like this explicitly with scalaz-stream `Process`:

```
def infiniteRandomProcess: Process[Rng, Int] =
  Process.await(Rng.int)({
    i => Process.emit(i) ++ infiniteRandomProcess
  })
```

Then you transform the lazy `Process` until you get something you're happy to `run` (or `runLog` or so on), and you end up with an `Rng` value (or perhaps a monad transformer that combines this with e.g. `Task`).

The API might allow converting this to a `Stream`; there's a lot of it and I tend to stay around the shallow end.